# Convert DB2 Query to SQL Server to output a grouped column in XML Format

Tags: sql-server, xml, db2, sql-server-2019, for-xml

I have the following code in a select statement today for a DB2 Database which does work. I would like to convert this code for SQL Server 2019. So far, I haven't found anything that would replicate the same output.

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN APPLICATION = 'APP1' THEN 'APPLICATION1'
    WHEN APPLICATION = 'APP2' THEN 'APPLICATION2'
    ELSE NULL
END AS "ACCESS",
XMLSERIALIZE (
             CONTENT XMLELEMENT(
              NAME "Users",
              XMLAGG(
               XMLELEMENT(
                NAME "User",
                XMLELEMENT (NAME "NAME", USERID),
                XMLELEMENT (NAME "FIRST", RTRIM(FIRST)),
                XMLELEMENT (NAME "LAST", RTRIM(LAST)),
                XMLELEMENT (NAME "FROM", RTRIM(SUBMITTEDBY_ID)),
                XMLELEMENT (NAME "DISPLAYNAME", RTRIM(DISPLAYNAME))
               )
               ORDER BY APPLICATION
              )
             )
             AS CLOB (30K)
) AS "USERLIST"

GROUP BY APPLICATION
From RequestTable
```

The output has one column called ACCESS and the second column would be called USERLIST and that column would be an XML formatted output.

| ACCESS | USERLIST |
| --- | --- |
| APPLICATION1 | `<Users><User><NAME>user1</NAME><FIRST>givenName1</FIRST><LAST>surName1</LAST><FROM>manager</FROM><DISPLAYNAME>givenName1 surName1</DISPLAY></User><User><NAME>user2</NAME><FIRST>givenName2</FIRST><LAST>surName2</LAST><FROM>manager</FROM><DISPLAYNAME>givenName2 surName2</DISPLAY></User></Users>` |
| APPLICATION2 | `<Users><User><NAME>user3</NAME><FIRST>givenName3</FIRST><LAST>surName3</LAST><FROM>manager</FROM><DISPLAYNAME>givenName3 surName3</DISPLAY></User></Users>` |

Does SQL Server have similar functionality I can take advantage of?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Comment: It is very easy to implement in MS SQL Server. Please provide ##1-4.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I supplied the code as it works in DB2, along with a table of the output. I can't find similar functionality in SQL Server. The desired output is the table above as it's handled in the DB2 query.

It's running SQL Server 2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in **a single scan of the base table**, by using `STRING_AGG`. Unfortunately, SQL Server does not support `XML_AGG`, which would have made this significantly easier.

```sql
SELECT
  ACCESS = IIF(APPLICATION = 'APP1', 'APPLICATION1', 'APPLICATION2'), 
  USERLIST = CAST('<Users>' + STRING_AGG(x.xml, '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY USERID) + '</Users>' AS xml)
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      t.USERID,
      t.FIRST,
      t.LAST,
      t.SUBMITTEDBY_ID AS [FROM],
      t.DISPLAYNAME 
    FOR XML PATH('User')
) x(xml)
GROUP BY APPLICATION;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/qNp4pISN)

Comment: Two questions going with this method. The first, where would I add a WHERE statement if I wanted to filter the results down? Would it be inside the CROSS APPLY? The second question is can I use multiple tables in the FROM statement if I needed data from multiple tables or am I limited to a single table?

Comment: No outside it, just above `GROUP BY`, because the subquery has no `FROM` clause. Yes you can, but depends what results you want. If you need nested results then you need to aggregate the other table inside an `APPLY` or a subquery first. If you just want a big joined result you can do normal joins.

Comment: Once I figured out the WHERE and JOIN the way I needed them, this worked really well. The query returned really fast.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```sql
-- Create test data
-- drop table #data
select access
,   n.value('NAME[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)') AS USERID
,   n.value('FIRST[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)') AS FIRST
,   n.value('LAST[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)') AS LAST
,   n.value('FROM[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)') AS [SUBMITTEDBY_ID]
,   n.value('DISPLAYNAME[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)') AS [DISPLAYNAME]
into    #data
from (
    VALUES  (N'APPLICATION1', N'<Users><User><NAME>user1</NAME><FIRST>givenName1</FIRST><LAST>surName1</LAST><FROM>manager</FROM><DISPLAYNAME>givenName1 surName1</DISPLAYNAME></User><User><NAME>user2</NAME><FIRST>givenName2</FIRST><LAST>surName2</LAST><FROM>manager</FROM><DISPLAYNAME>givenName2 surName2</DISPLAYNAME></User></Users>')
    ,   (N'APPLICATION2', N'<Users><User><NAME>user3</NAME><FIRST>givenName3</FIRST><LAST>surName3</LAST><FROM>manager</FROM><DISPLAYNAME>givenName3 surName3</DISPLAYNAME></User></Users>')
) t (ACCESS,USERLIST)
cross apply (
    select cast(userlist as xml) AS x
    ) x
cross apply x.x.nodes('Users/User') n(n)

-- Generate query
select  ACCESS, (SELECT USERID, FIRST, LAST, SUBMITTEDBY_ID AS [FROM], DISPLAYNAME FROM #data d where d.access = x.access ORDER BY USERID for xml path('User'), ROOT('Users')) AS USERLIST
from    (
    SELECT access
    FROM    #data
    group by access
    ) x
```

There's no group by XML thingy in SQL Server, but you can group by the source data, and then use a correlated subquery to join together table another time for the XML source.

I added a dummy order by on userId, you can probably fix it to order by something else.

Comment: I will give this a try. Would there be other ways to group the data to have a similar output even if it's not XML? Basically I need all the user data to be grouped by the common application with the second column still being multivalued.

Comment: Yes, check out STRING_AGG function for SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

It is following the same **minimal reproducible example** pattern. You copy it to SSMS as-is, run it, and it is working.

It is better to use native XML datatype in SQL Server. It occupies much less storage because it is compressed. All this in comparison with CLOB, a.k.a. VARCHAR(MAX) in MS SQL Server parlance.  Also, XML data type has a powerful  XQuery/XSD based API to deal with.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (
    APPLICATION CHAR(4), 
    USERID VARCHAR(20),
    FIRST VARCHAR(20),
    LAST VARCHAR(20),
    SUBMITTEDBY_ID VARCHAR(20),
    DISPLAYNAME VARCHAR(20)
);
INSERT @tbl (APPLICATION, USERID, FIRST, LAST, SUBMITTEDBY_ID, DISPLAYNAME) VALUES
('APP1', 'user1', 'givenName1', 'surName1', 'manager', 'givenName1'),
('APP1', 'user2', 'givenName2', 'surName2', 'manager', 'givenName2'),
('APP2', 'user3', 'givenName3', 'surName3', 'manager', 'givenName3');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT ACCESS = IIF(APPLICATION = 'APP1', 'APPLICATION1', 'APPLICATION2'), 
    (SELECT USERID, FIRST, LAST, SUBMITTEDBY_ID AS [FROM], DISPLAYNAME 
    FROM @tbl AS c -- c(hild)
    WHERE c.APPLICATION = p.APPLICATION 
    ORDER BY USERID 
    FOR xml path('User'), TYPE, ROOT('Users')) AS USERLIST
FROM @tbl AS p -- p(arent)
GROUP BY APPLICATION;
```

Comment: There's no need for a self-join, you can just use `STRING_AGG` over a correlated subquery (with no `FROM` in it)

Comment: At the moment we didn't know what SQL Server version the OP is using